# how to make my "Login" use case prerequisite to other usecases in UML

Tags: uml, use-case, prerequisites

I'm creating a UseCase diagram for a library management system . I have a "Login" usecase which every actor should do befor going to other usecases . in other words , I want to show that "Login" usecase is the prerequisite to other usecases . 
anyone know how to show this ?
thanks

Answer (score 8):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use the `<<include>>` relation, where every UC `<<includes>>` login as the first step
2. Set a pre-condition on every UC that User must have logged in
3. Create an Actor named "Logged in User" (or similar) and show all your Use Cases related to it.

Which you choose depends on a number of factors.  (1) is simple and intuitive but doesn't really scale well on a diagram if you've lots of Use Cases.  (2) works well if you're documenting Use Cases textually - but doesn't show up on diagrams.  (3) might not be conventional, but can provide more scalability than (1) while still be viewable on a diagram.  However it breaks down if you have multiple Actors, each of which must be logged in to perform their UCs.

I personally tend to use (2).  If I need a UC diagram I'll include a "Login" UC on it but won't show relation from it to other UCs.

One option I wouldn't recommend is the `<<extend>>` relation, where every UC `<<extends>>` the login UC.  It doesn't really work semantically and suffers the same scalability issues as (1) above.

hth.

Comment: thanks sfinnie . I searched the web for preconditions on usecases . there were many answers , but none of them showed a diagram with preconditions .I wonder if it's a comment or something shape .  if you can show me what it's like on the diagram I'll be appreciated .

Comment: There's no standard syntax for showing pre-conditions on UCDs (that's why I said "...doesn't show up on diagrams...").  Pre-conditions only show up in the textual UC spec behind the oval on the diagram.  If you do need to show on a diagram, you could put the secured UCs in a separate package on the diagram (package named e.g. "secured domain tasks" or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to an `<<includes>>` relationship in this case is a `<<precedes>>` dependency.  This makes it clearer that login must *precede* the use case rather than simply occurs at some point during a use case.

Enterprise Architect includes such a stereotyped dependency in its Use Case toolbox, but you could otherwise create your own stereotyped dependency.  The EA documentation on this states:

> *Invokes* and *Precedes* relationships are defined by the Open Modelling Language (OML). They are stereotyped Dependency relationships; Invokes indicates that Use Case A, at some point, causes Use Case B to happen, whilst Precedes indicates that Use Case C must complete before Use Case D can begin.

You may not want to introduce OML idioms to your UML, but the feature does exactly what you want and is visible at the diagram level.

Answer (score 0):

UCs are useful for many things, but most importantly for communication. If you start using relationships on UC diagrams, your communication benefits drop down a notch. Same with copy pasting prerequisite "user X must be logged on" in each UC, etc.

Most importantly UCs are not intended to be complete system specification. So simply put it somewhere else, for example:

- as a rule in overall system rules list
- as a table in "user access rights" spec section